Professional killer fools someone into doing a hit job with a fake diagnosis
I remember this fine English language film set in Europe, where one of the characters, a calm professional killer, out of some minor grouse, sets up his neighbor to do a hit job after fooling him into thinking that he is terminally ill. The killing happens on a train (in Germany, I think). When retribution comes to the neighbor, the calm killer defends the house and kills the invaders. The neighbor dies in the process. In a memorable final scene, the killer's wife spits on his face after she understands what happened, he just wipes it off with a window blind and goes away.
Further details: The calm professional killer had a wife. I remember reading that this anti-hero character is from a novel series, where he is bisexual.
I remember watching it about a decade ago, but don't recall where it was made or where I watched it. This is not an animated movie.
Can you tell me the title?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question and flag it for reopening once you feel confident you did so.

Done. I'm flagging it for reopening.

Thanks, reopened. You seem to remember some of the scenes quite well, do you also happen to remember how the characters looked or maybe some characterisitic places?

Ah found it now (added an answer) - thanks!

Got it! Googling with my clues helped me find it: Ripley's game. Details that check out include:

The "spit scene"
the killing in a train
attack on the neighbor
terminal illness of the neighbor

Some other details don't check out. (I must have misremembered.)

Please try to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more and for the question and its answers to be useful for other users.
